# PayPal Subscriptions APIs Integration

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I try to integrate the Subscriptions API to my website.
First of all, I'm not sure if I should use this API or the billing agreement API, all I want is to bill my costumers with a fix amount each month...

I'm using the latest integration steps recommended by PayPal:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/subscriptions

Anyway,

I have created a product, a plan and a subscription,
At the end I got an id (I-2PR5ANJT6J4C)

I try to use this id in the PayPal button:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=ILS"></script>
<script>paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        shape: 'pill'
    },
    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'production'
    // Set up the payment:
    // 1. Add a payment callback
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        // 2. Make a request to your server
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            return resolve('I-2PR5ANJT6J4C');
        })
    },
    // Execute the payment:
    // 1. Add an onAuthorize callback
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        // 2. Make a request to your server
        return actions.request.post('/my-api/execute-payment/', {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            payerID:   data.payerID
        })
            .then(function(res) {
                // 3. Show the buyer a confirmation message.
            });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');</script>
```

And I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: I-2PR5ANJT6J4C does not match pattern for order-id, ec-token or cart-id
```

Anyone else faced this issue? How can I pass the subscription id to the button to work correctly?

Thanks,
Assaf

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit older, but in case you or someone else ist still looking for an answer, simply use `createSubscription` instead of `createOrder`:

```
createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
    // 2. Make a request to your server
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        return resolve('I-2PR5ANJT6J4C');
    })
}
```